# Manually inject service in asp.net core mvc6?

Tags: dependency-injection, asp.net-core-mvc

I want to use DI to manually inject an `IDBConnection` in my api controllers.  I know I can put it in the constructor:

```
public MyController(IDBConnection cnn) { this._Connection = cnn; }
```

Or I could use the `[FromServices]` attribute:

```
[FromServices]
public IDbConnection _Connection { get; set; }
```

And I can use it in views like this:

```
@inject IDbConnection cnn
```

What I would really like to do would be to have it in a `using`, and have the DI open the connection so I could do something like this:

```
using (var cnn = Services.Inject<IDbConnection>()) {
    // do something, don't worry about opening or closing
}
```

I'm declaring it like this:

```
services.AddTransient<IDbConnection>(x =>
{
    string connectionString = Configuration.Get<string>(
           "Data:DefaultConnection:ConnectionString");
    return new SqlConnection(connectionString);
});
```

Should I create a class inheriting from `SqlConnection` that calls `Open()` in it's constructor?  How can I access `Configuration` from there?  I could create it like that to inject configuration or the connect string...  Is `using` not required?  Is there basically no overhead with just creating the instance so it wouldn't matter if some actions needed multiple connections to different databases?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend that you create a service layer that your controller will depend on instead of directly accessing the db connection (and you won't have to this in your views `@inject IDbConnection cnn`). Your views should only declare the Model that your controller method returns and you will have nice intellisense support in the view pages.

```
public class ProductServices(){
   public ProductServices(IDbConnection conn){
     ...
  }

  public List<Product> GetProducts(){
    ...
  }
}
```

`using` is not required. As a rule of thumb, if the instance is created via IoC container (eg. Unity, Autofac, Ninject, etc),  it should also be destroyed by the IoC container.